# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(name: string) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to learn Typescript, here is a Menu component that I created, however I could not be able to figure out they error shows in menu.tsx line . 42

which is the line `return React.cloneElement(child, newProps);`

Would appreciate if someone can point me out

Menu.tsx

```
export interface MenuProps {
  defaultActiveItem?: string;
  className?: string;
  onClick?: (name: string) => never;
}

class Menu extends Component<MenuProps> {
  static Item = MenuItem;
  state = {
    selected: this.props.defaultActiveItem
  };

  handleMenuClick = (name: string) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: name
    });
    if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick(name);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      children,
      className,
      onClick,
      defaultActiveItem,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    const computedClasses = classnames(className);
    const childrenWithNewProps = React.Children.map(
      children,
      (child: React.ReactElement<ItemProps>) => {
        const newProps = {
          handleMenuClick: this.handleMenuClick,
          active: this.state.selected === child.props.name
        };
        return React.cloneElement(child, newProps);
      }
    );
    return (
      <ul className={computedClasses} {...rest}>
        {childrenWithNewProps}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

MenuItem.tsx

```
export interface ItemProps {
  handleMenuClick?: (name: string) => void;
  name: string;
  active?: boolean;
  children?: any;
}

const defaultProps = {
  active: false
};

const MenuItem: React.StatelessComponent<ItemProps> = ({
  handleMenuClick,
  name,
  active,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const computedClasses = classnames(styles.menuItem, {
    [styles.selected]: active
  });

  return (
    <li
      className={computedClasses}
      onClick={() => handleMenuClick && handleMenuClick(name)}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </li>
  );
};

MenuItem.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default MenuItem;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/n4lvv0m2vl

Comment: Could you please also post the code that throws the error in the question?

Comment: sure, I would expect to be actually better have a code sandbox, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on line 42 is very clear.

```
export interface ItemProps {
  handleMenuClick?: (name: string) => void;
  name: string;
  active?: boolean;
  children?: any;
}
```

In the interface, you've defined `handleMenuClick` as being optional (by adding the "?" at the end of the name). `cloneElement` requires `handleMenuClick` not to be optional.

As for codesandbox not handling tsx files, see [this issue on github](https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/220).

Comment: got it! what do you suggest? I have 2 ideas on mind, 1st. create a new type for the `newProps` . 2nd used the same `ItemProp` interface, but I would I have to manual spread the original props, which cloneElement already do